# react-window: How to use actual table tags

Tags: reactjs, react-window

I want to use the semantic HTML tags (instead of using divs) to create a table with react-window.

**The problem is that List (FixedSizedList) creates two wrappers.** The other one is called `outerElementType` and is also a prop to `FixedSizedList` with default value `div`. This means that I can't create the proper table structure, and that all the `td` ends up in the first column . It looks like neither of these ones can be omitted.
How do I get around this?

Current code:

```
import { FixedSizeList as List } from "react-window";

...

return (

   <table className="CargoListTable">
      <CargoTableHead />
      <List
        height={600}
        itemCount={cargoList.length}
        itemSize={35}
        width={900}
        itemData={cargoList}
        innerElementType="tbody"
      >
        {Row}
      </List>
   </table>
 )

const Row: React.FC<RowProps> = ({ index, style, data }) => {
  const cargo = data[index];
  return (
    <tr
      style={style}
      key={index}
    >
      <td>{cargo.registrationNumber}</td>
      <td>{cargo.pol}</td>
      <td>{cargo.pod}</td>
    </tr>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution to this would be to have the entire table inside the list. We can use a modified version of the [sticky-header example](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window#does-this-library-support-sticky-items) from react-window for this.

You can view a working example in this CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-dust-jtf42?file=/src/index.js

We will need two simple elements to render `StickyRow` and `Row` elements. You can add `td` elements here.

```
const Row = ({ index, style }) => (
  <tr className="row" style={style}>
    Row {index}
  </tr>
);

const StickyRow = ({ index, style }) => (
  <tr className="sticky" style={style}>
    <th>Sticky Row {index}</th>
  </tr>
);
```

We wrap the `FixedSizeList` in a Context that contains the sticky rows. In this case only the first row would be sticky.

```
const StickyList = ({ children, stickyIndices, ...rest }) => (
  <StickyListContext.Provider value={{ ItemRenderer: children, stickyIndices }}>
    <List itemData={{ ItemRenderer: children, stickyIndices }} {...rest}>
      {ItemWrapper}
    </List>
  </StickyListContext.Provider>
);
```

`ItemWrapper` renders only the non-sticky rows using the method passed in the main render function(ie- `{Row}`). This takes care of rendering the table data.

```
const ItemWrapper = ({ data, index, style }) => {
  const { ItemRenderer, stickyIndices } = data;
  if (stickyIndices && stickyIndices.includes(index)) {
    return null;
  }
  return <ItemRenderer index={index} style={style} />;
};
```

To render the table headers, we need a custom innerElementType.

```
const innerElementType = forwardRef(({ children, ...rest }, ref) => (
  <StickyListContext.Consumer>
    {({ stickyIndices }) => (
      <table ref={ref} {...rest}>
        {stickyIndices.map(index => (
          <StickyRow
            index={index}
            key={index}
            style={{ top: index * 35, left: 0, width: "100%", height: 35 }}
          />
        ))}

        <tbody>
          {children}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )}
  </StickyListContext.Consumer>
));
```

This element is aware of the sticky indices because of the context. And renders the header and the body.

This code could be simplified further if it suites your needs.